# Why is it more common to draw in arithmetic subdivisions in logarithmic plots?

Tags: logarithms, graphing-functions

I can understand that you'd sometimes want to see where the linear subdivisions are on a logarithmic plot, and track e.g. where one y-value is ~3 times as large as another y-value (e.g. 2x10^5 compared to 6x10^5), and so on, but why is this the most common way of drawing such plots?

At least in my view, when drawing a logarithmic plot, I'm more interested in the geometric relationships between the values than the arithmetic ones. In other words, again assuming a plot with a logarithmic y-axis, why isn't it more common to space the values along that axis evenly so that they're separated by the same factor rather than the same addend? E.g. for a plot with major subdivisions of a factor of 10 (which are spaced equally, as one would expect), considering e.g. the values from 10^4 to 10^5, why is it almost always that the values 2x10^4, 3x10^4, 4x10^4, and so on, are drawn in, rather than 10^4.1, 10^4.2, 10^4.3,and so on?

Of course the logarithmic plots themselves work exactly that way, so any distance along a logarithmic axis will represent the exact same factor as the same distance anywhere else on the axis, but it's still strange to me that you rarely ever see the actual geometric relationships represented graphically in that way. After all it's quite common in various other fields, like how frequencies are equally spaced along a keyboard in that manner (but with a factor of 2^(1/12) per semitone rather than the factor of 10^(1/10) per step I mentioned above).

Comment: Well... usually when I display things on a log-plot I'm also interested in the decimal values, simply because that's how I'm accustomed to read numbers. Particularly in applications when the axes have units - I don't want to have to mentally compute 10^4.3 to get that value.  The exponent 4.3 does not have a meaningful unit and so seems less fundamental. But of course you are free to draw it however it's most useful! It's just a matter of taste really.